# Will CPU cache accelerate writing/reading a new file?

Tags: caching, file-io, io, operating-system

Suppose CPU cache size is 1MB.

1. I am writing a NEW file of size 1 MB. Will the CPU cache accelerate the write by caching block by block and then flushing ?
2. Now a case where file size is greater than CPU cache size, say 2 MB. Will the CPU cache accelerate writing to it, assuming it can cache file blocks of size say 4kb ?
3. Will the CPU cache thus accelerate reading file say of size 1GB, by caching file blocks after 1st block access ?

Answer (score 0):

Reading a file generally means that a program calls a `read` system call or the like, and gets a private, modifiable copy of the requested data in its own address space.

It is possible, but unlikely that the requested data has been cached in memory, and that the memory in turn was cached on the CPU, and the copy effectively occurs entirely within the cache.

Somewhat more likely is that you memory-map the file and access it from different processes. This will help leverage the cache. Writing to shared memory can implement inter-process communication, even as the memory is backed by a file which may or may not ever go to the disk at all. A cache only stores recently used data though, so it is only effective as long as you keep accessing the same 1 MB (or however much it holds).

CPU cache will not help getting data written (flushed) to disk. The disk is by definition slower than the CPU, so it is inherently the weakest link.

Comment: What if I am writing records of size say 1kb, to file of size 1MB and CPU cache of 1 MB. So if the file is cached in CPU, can't the writes be accelerated ? Initially there shall be no caching, but after the write of 1st record, the 1MB file may be cached and subsequent writes can be very fast. Isin't it possible ?

Comment: @sapthrishi007 Files are managed by the operating system, and modifying a file requires a context switch into the OS kernel, unless it is memory-mapped. The context switch will kill performance even if the data is stored in the CPU. You seem a bit confused about how performance works, and computer memory.